# muxing видео в ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Есть видеофайл video1.mp4 длиной 11 минут и есть видео файл video2.avi длиной 45 секунд. Подскажите, как их смиксовать `ffmpeg`, чтобы video2.avi файл наложился на video1.mp4 файл на 5 минуте (FPS и разрешения обоих файлов одинаковые) на выходе `mp4` файл.

Answer (score 2):

отвечу:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.avi -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=1:1:enable='between(t,300,345)'" output.mp4
```